# Iterating over Stream in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to iterate over logs from a docker container by using the `bollard` crate.

Here's my code:

```rust
use std::default::Default;

use bollard::container::LogsOptions;
use bollard::Docker;

fn main() {
    let docker = Docker::connect_with_http_defaults().unwrap();

    let options = Some(LogsOptions::<String>{
        stdout: true,
        ..Default::default()
    });

    let data = docker.logs("2f6c52410d", options);
    // ...
}
```

`docker.logs()` returns `impl Stream<Item = Result<LogOutput, Error>>`. I'd like to iterate over the results, but I have no idea how to do that. I've managed to find an example that uses `try_collect::<Vec<LogOutput>>()` from the `future_utils` crate, but I'd like to iterate over the results in a while loop instead of collecting the results in a vector. I know that I can iterate over a vector, but performing tasks in a loop will be better for my use case.

I've tried to call `poll_next()` method for the stream, but it requires a mysterious `Context` object which I don't understand. The `poll_next()` method was unavailable until I've used `pin_mut!()` macro on the stream.

How do I iterate over stream? What should I read to understand what's going on here? I know that the streams are related to `Futures`, but calling `await` or `next()` doesn't work here.

Answer (score 10):

You typically bring in your library of choice's StreamExt trait, and then do something like

```
while let Some(foo) = stream.next().await {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by `bring in your library of choice's StreamExt trait`? The stream doesn't have the `next()` method.

Comment: @Djent [`futures::stream::StreamExt`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html) adds extension methods like `next()` for `Stream`s.

Comment: Tokio also has one. Not sure what the difference is between them.